# How can be increase the size of hairs?

Tags: blender

In blender I'm trying to use the hair particles and I'd like to increase their size

There are many options in blender 2.8 where size is explicitly mentioned but none of the actually modifies the size of my hair.

I'd just like to increase the radius of the hair nothing more... I really couldn't find anything online after many checks

Comment: If your using evee, set the [hair type to strip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126837/935), if your using cycles, set the viewport display to rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial hair length in the particle tab. In the *particle edit* mode you can grow/shrink hair as well.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem is solved completely with the answer of @sambler. You can change whatever thing you want about the hair size but you won't see any of this (except for the hair length). What you have to do is to instruct your render engine as he suggested:

[Select strip and enjoy size modification (this is done in eeve in cycles the procedure is similar and sambler told that)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47qy.png)